# Where to find the ISO file to be burned on a CD/DVD?

Tags: iso

I haven't found a useful answer to similar questions. I have downloaded Ubuntu 12.01 to my desktop running Windows 7 and it seems to work fine. But I want to make a CD/DVD to be able to boot Linux on another desktop PC. I can see that I get an ISO file as a result of the download, but as soon as I unzip it there is no longer an ISO file. Please help.
Finn Nielsen

Comment: Simply right click on `ISO` image and select `Burn disc image`.

Comment: What program are you using to "unzip"

Comment: Are you saying that the `.iso` file is actually *missing* now, or are you just saying that the files you get out of unzipping it don't have an `.iso` file?

Comment: Did you tell Internet Explorer to "Open" the file when saving the download, instead you want to click "Save" , location of opened files - http://superuser.com/questions/180254/where-does-internet-explorer-save-downloaded-files-that-are-merely-opened , http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090608104737AAFgSvK

Comment: When I used Internet Explorer instead of Mozilla Firefox to download Ubuntu - IT WORKED. Thank you for your answers. Finn Nielsen

Comment: seems like the auto opening of downloads in firefox is kikcing in, to change the settings http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/616643-stop-firefox-auto-opening-files-after-download/

Comment: You download the file from ubuntu.com/download but DO NOT UNZIP IT.
Instead, Burn the file to a CD and re-insert it. Then it should install.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to unzip an ISO file.  You can burn it directly to CD using Brasero if you're already using Ubuntu, or if you are using Windows, you can use programs like Nero, PowerISO, or WinISO.

While some archive programs will let you treat an ISO file like an archive and extract its contents, fundamentally an ISO file is an *image* for a disk. Extracting the ISO is a completely separate operation than *burning* it, which is what you want to do.

The [official installation instructions explain how you can burn the ISO on a Windows system](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-windows), after downloading it.

For more information and other programs that you can use, [see this page](http://www.petri.co.il/how_to_write_iso_files_to_cd.htm).